# AppCompatButton loses background color after new activity added

Tags: android, button

Hello I have an application which at first it started with a splash screen and then it took you to the main activity in here I have code for an appcompatButton, this button was styled with a blue background. I decided to add another activity before the main activity, this activity also includes the same type of button and style. However, when the user clicks the button they are taken to the main activity in which the button now shows white. I am a bit confused there is no code in my project to tell it to change the background color. any ideas would be great!

welcome activity (new one added):

xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/continue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:text="Continue"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_below="@id/message"/>
```

welcomeActivity:

```
continueButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.continue);
continueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {               
                showMainActivity();
            }
        });
```

Main Activity:

xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not close welcomeActivity?

```
continueButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.continue);
continueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {               
                showMainActivity();
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Because I think the background color(white) of the welcomeActivity is carried on to the button in the main activity.

---

Add these flags to your splashscreen acitivity

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

---

Try setting the splash screen theme seperately from the app theme.

Comment: Thank you for your response I was thinking the same, I just added the finish(); line but I still encounter this error, also weird thing is the other activites and fragments are experiencing this as well. but when I remove this first activity from my code all the button colors go back to normal

Comment: have you added in manifest, <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> for your welcomeActivity?

Comment: because it looks like your welcomeActivity is the first activity now.

Comment: yes i have, technically the splah screen that comes before is an activity on its own and this one includes this code in the manifest

Comment: Just want to check one more time. Are you sure the problem is with the welcomeactivity, not the splashactivity?

Comment: Do you think so? There are no buttons here just a screen delay of 2 seconds and loads some information on the background, however, if I tell my app to go form splashscreen to main activity button show normal, is only when it goes form splash screen to welcome to main that the issue occurs

Comment: Yeah I think so because I have experienced the similar. Try excluding the splashactivity and launch with the welcomeactivity.

Comment: do you mean to merge my splash screen with my welcome activity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151998/discussion-between-ray-hong-and-paul590).